# Why Spring Pageable returns unexpected result?

Tags: java, spring-data-jpa

In db table `products` I have 12 records. Ids from 1 to 12. I call db using JpaRepository which extends PagingAndSortingRepository. Can't understand:

1. Why Pageable doesn't return expected result (size)?
2. Also I can't get product with id:1. why it happens?
3. why pageble doesn't start from id:1, then 2 and etc?

Please advise.

API `/getPageable/{page}/{size}`

I call `/getPageable/1/10` and get list of `2 elements`.

I call `/getPageable/1/9` and get `3 elements`

```
/getPageable/1/8 - 4 elements ids: 10, 11, 12, 5 
/getPageable/1/7 - 5 elements ids: 9, 10, 11, 12, 5 
/getPageable/1/6 - 6 elements ids: 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 5 
/getPageable/1/5 - 5 elements ids: 7, 8, 9, 10, 11 
/getPageable/1/4 - 4 elements ids: 6, 7, 8, 9 
/getPageable/1/3 - 3 elements ids: 4, 6, 7 
/getPageable/1/2 - 2 elements ids: 3, 4 
/getPageable/1/1 - 1 element id:2

/getPageable/2/1 - 1 element id: 3
/getPageable/2/2 - 2 elements ids: 6, 7
/getPageable/2/3 - 3 elements ids: 8, 9, 10
/getPageable/2/4 - 4 elements ids: 10, 11, 12, 5
/getPageable/2/5 - 2 elements ids: 12, 5
/getPageable/2/6 - 0 elements
/getPageable/2/7 - 0 elements
/getPageable/2/8 - 0 elements
```

Controller code:

```
 @GET
        @Path("/getPageable/{pageId}/{size}")
        @Produces({"application/json"})
        @ApiOperation(value = "Get randomly list of products")
        @ApiResponses(value = {
                @ApiResponse(code = 200, message = "OK"),
                @ApiResponse(code = 500, message = "Something wrong in Server")})
        @ApiImplicitParams({
                @ApiImplicitParam(name = "X-Auth-Token", value = "Authorization token", required = true, dataType = "string", paramType = "header")
        })
        public List<Product> getProductsRandomly(@PathParam("pageId") Integer pageId, @PathParam("size") Integer size) {

            Pageable pageable = new PageRequest(pageId, size);

            return  productDao.findPageable(pageable).getContent();
        }
```

productDao

```
@Repository
public class ProductDao extends BaseDao<Product, Integer> {

    @Autowired
    private ProductRepository productRepository;
....
}
```

productResopitory

```
public interface ProductRepository extends JpaRepository<Product, Integer> {
...
}
```

`JpaRepository extends PagingAndSortingRepository` which has method `Page<T> findAll(Pageable var1);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try subtracting 1 into pageId. As database also start indexing with 0.

```
        Pageable pageable = new PageRequest(pageId-1, size);
```

Comment: Happy to help you.